# WordPress woocommerce PHP add to cart error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, bundle, product

Trying to figure out a woocommerce PHP add to cart error. Get this message flash across the browser window and then loads normally.

> "Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/customer/www/mydiycenter.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ext_product_bundles/extendons-woocommerce-product-bundles-front.php"

Following PHP lines in question below.

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($cart_item_data['variation_bundle']);$i++){
  if($cart_item_data['variation_bundle'][$i] != ""){
    array_push($loopnum, $allKeys[$i]);
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: sizeof -> count

Comment: The problem is with an external plugin.0¿ Have you tried to contact the devs of that plugin?

Comment: @WPPunk sizeof -> count did not work